# Laravel Blade @yield variable scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have two pages that are almost identical. One shows a list of users, the other shows the same list, but with more verbose information.
So I am calling two views that extend the same wrapper. However, Laravel complains that $user is not defined in verbose.blade.php. I am passing $users to the view which seems to be available to content.blade.php but the $user that is created within the foreach loop doesn't seem to be accessible in verbose.blade.php.

verbose.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.content')

@section('user')
    {{ dd($user) }}
@endsection
```

nonverbose.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.content')

@section('user')
    {{ dd($user) }}
@endsection
```

content.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
    @foreach($users as $user)
        @yield('user')
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

I have also tried `@yield('user', ['user' => $user])`

How would I go about making $user available in verbose.blade.php?

Comment: just out of curiosity (i know this would fix the error, but I don't know if it would be a solution) have you included the user as a value in your controller function `return view('verbose', compact('users', 'user'))` ?

Comment: I assume your controller has something like `return view('verbose', compact('users');`?

Comment: If this is not Laravel 3 you shouldn't be using `@endsection` try `@stop` instead.

Comment: @Ben Yes, I do have that

Comment: @saadel is that so? Where in the documentation is that?

Comment: @Votemike either `@show` or `@stop`:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#blade-templating

Answer (score 2):

Did you have tried to use @include?

```
@include('user', ['user' => $user])
```

Comment: I like this answer too. If he made a partials/user.blade.php, this would work nicely.

Comment: If I were to do it like this, how would I specify whether I wanted the verbose or non-verbose partial? Maybe my question wasn't clear that I need to switch between two views. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because of the order that Laravel parses blade templates in.

Sometimes we programmers get so engrained in our "don't repeat yourself (DRY)" principle that we take it too far. This is one of those times -- you should simply put the foreach loop directly into verbose.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
    @foreach($users as $user)
        @yield('user')
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: There is actually more info within the foreach in content.blade.php I'd rather not put all of that inside my verbose blade and nonverbose blade. But if that's what I have to do, I'll do that.